# Clear Div Content Inside Function

Tags: javascript

I have use 2 functions i want when i click on button it should clear the output of first function result but it does not work when i use .innerHTML = ""; how to do it?

```
function HalfRightTriangle() {
        for (var i = 1; i <=7; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <i; j++) {
            // document.write("*"); 
             document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "*";
          } // end of inner for loop 
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>";
       } // end of outer for loop 
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "";
    } // function end
```

Comment: I only see one function.

Comment: I don't see  `.innerHTML = ""` anywhere

Comment: I believe you are missing some code... or missing the plus in `...innerHTML [+]= ""`

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using text, it may be better to just work with a variable, and then set it to innerHTML when done.

Something like this:

```
function HalfRightTriangle() {
    var inner = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j < i; j++) {
            inner += "*";
        } // end of inner for loop
        inner += "<br>";
    } // end of outer for loop
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inner;
} // function end
```

Comment: Could you provide additional information? What does the html look like that has an id of "result"? It's possible something in that layout is causing a problem. The HTML above should work.

Comment: <body>
   
   <button type="button" onclick="HalfRightTriangle();"> Half Right Triangle </button> 
   <button type="button" onclick="HalfLeftTriangle();"> Half Left Triangle </button> 
   <br><br>
   <div id="result"> Result Here </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please also make sure your javascript is located in the head of the page (or the bottom of the page). If you're calling that section via onLoad, it will fail.  See this fiddle as an example of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ptts3wh8/

Comment: Did that help Jyotishina?

Answer (score 0):

if you use container control show your result then inner html work but if don't have container control then use val function of java script.
example

```
<div id=result>

<label id=result></label>

</div>
<script type=text/java script>

$('#result').html("")

$('#result').val("")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function HalfRightTriangle() {
        for (var i = 1; i <=7; i++) {
            for (var j = 1; j <i; j++) {

                // document.write("*"); 
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "*";

            } // end of inner for loop 

            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>";

        } // end of outer for loop 


    } // function end

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";

    function HalfLeftTriangle() {
        for (var i = 7; i >=1; i--) {
            for (var j = 1; j <=i; j++) {

                // document.write("*"); 
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "*";

            } <!-- end of inner for loop -->

            //document.write("<br>");
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "<br>";
        } <!-- end of outer for loop -->

    } // function end
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";


</script>
</head>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="HalfRightTriangle();"> Half Right Triangle </button>
<button type="button" onclick="HalfLeftTriangle();"> Half Left Triangle </button>
<br><br>
<div id="result"> Result Here </div>
```

Comment: Whole code is that i want after click on first it should clear contents then execute other button code function..